# Issue with Laravel Passport /logout

Tags: laravel

I've encountered a problem with the straightforward logout functionality in Laravel Passport.

Upon logging in, the system correctly generates a Bearer token, and using this token for a GET request yields the expected result. However, during the logout process, it indicates that the user is not authenticated and prevents me from deleting the token from the database.

I'm including the implemented functions below for your review:

```
public function apiLogin(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])) {
        // successfull authentication
        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

        $user_token['token'] = $user->createToken('appToken')->accessToken;

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'token' => $user_token,
            'user' => $user,
        ], 200);
    } else {
        // failure to authenticate
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Failed to authenticate.',
        ], 401);
    }
}

/**
 * Metodo per gestire il logout API.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function apiLogout(Request $request)

{
    if (Auth::user()) {
        $request->user()->token()->revoke();

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Logged out successfully',
        ], 200);
    }
}
```

when attempting to log out, allow me to delete the token from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after revoking the token also delete that token.

```
public function apiLogout(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->user()) {
        $request->user()->token()->revoke();
        $request->user()->token()->delete();

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Logged out successfully',
        ], 200);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'User not authenticated',
        ], 401);
    }
}
```

and also make sure your logout route is protected with auth Api middleware.

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    // authenticated routes
});
```

Comment: Then please make the answer the right answer. Happy I could help you out.